# R: How can I add titles based on grouping variable in word_associate?

Tags: r, nlp, word-cloud

I am using the [word_associate package](https://rdrr.io/cran/qdap/man/word_associate.html) in R Markdown to create word clouds across a grouping variable with multiple categories. I would like the titles of each word cloud to be drawn from the character values of the grouping variable.

I have added trans_cloud(title=TRUE) to my code, but have not been able to resolve my problem. Here's my code, which runs but doesn't produce graphs with titles:

```
library(qdap)
word_associate(df$text, match.string=c("cat"), grouping.var=c(df$id), 
               text.unit="sentence", stopwords=c(Top200Words), wordcloud=TRUE, cloud.colors=c("#0000ff","#FF0000"), 
               trans_cloud(title=TRUE))
```

I have also tried the following, which does not run:

```
library(qdap)
word_associate(df$text, match.string=c("cat"), grouping.var=c(df$id), 
text.unit="sentence", stopwords=c(Top200Words), wordcloud=TRUE, cloud.colors=c("#0000ff","#FF0000"), 
title=TRUE)
```

Can anyone help me figure this out? I can't find any guidance in the documentation and there's hardly any examples of or discussions about word_associate on the web.

Here's an example data frame that reproduces the problem:

```
id          text
question1   I love cats even though I'm allergic to them.
question1   I hate cats because I'm allergic to them.
question1   Cats are funny, cute, and sweet.
question1   Cats are mean and they scratch me.     
question2   I only pet cats when I have my epipen nearby.
question2   I avoid petting cats at all cost.
question2   I visit a cat cafe every week. They have 100 cats.
question2   I tried to pet my friend's cat and it attacked me.
```

Note that if I run this in R (instead of Markdown), the figures automatically print the "question1_list1" and "question2_list1" in bright blue at the top of the figure file. This doesn't work for me because I need the titles to exclude "_list1" and be written in black. These automatically generated titles do not respond to changes in my trans_cloud specifications.
Ex:

```
library(qdap)
word_associate(df$text, match.string=c("cat"), grouping.var=c(df$id), 
               text.unit="sentence", stopwords=c(Top200Words), wordcloud=TRUE, cloud.colors=c("#0000ff","#FF0000"), 
               trans_cloud(title=TRUE, title.color="#000000"))
```

In addition, I'm locked in to using this package (as opposed to other options for creating word clouds in R) because I'm using it to create network plots, too.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of `df` that you use in your code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just edited my post to provide a small sample df.